# JVM Monitor char array memory usage

Tags: java, jvm, monitor

I'm creating a 4096 x 4096 array of my class. When I'm profiling, it's showing that the most memory is used by char arrays. I don't have any char arrays or strings in my class.

Here is my Java class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private boolean flag;


    public MyClass() {
        id = 0;
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

And my Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass[][] objects = new MyClass[4096][4096];

        for (int i = 0;i<4096;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<4096;j++) {
                objects[i][j] = new MyClass();
            }
        }

        while(true);
    }
}
```

I'm using JVM Monitor for profiling. Why is it showing this?

Here's a screenshot of it running in Eclipse:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse profile]

Comment: how did you perform your heap dump? did you run a GC up front to clean away all garbage?

Comment: which class your main method running from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image, it looks like the instances of `MyClass` you created aren't even live when you're doing the profiling.  The `char[]` usage is expected since char arrays back `String`s, which are used extensively in class definitions, etc.

It could be that your array is getting garbage collected since it's not used.  Try adding a line after the sleep that uses the array, and then try to profile again.  Example:

```
    MyClass[][] objects = new MyClass[4096][4096];
    for(int i = 0;i<4096;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<4096;j++)
        {
            objects[i][j] = new MyClass();

        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000000);
    System.out.println(objects[10][40]);
```

This ensures that the array is not eligible for garbage collection until you've had a chance to profile it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes that was the problem.

Comment: @user3332774 The profiler needs some memory to run and VisualVM in particular creates lots of objects when running.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you run System.gc() or similar before taking your heap dump. Else you will see a lot of objects that are no longer referenced in your sample.

Comment: I updated my code. This is the only code in my project.

Comment: replace while(true) with: System.gc(): Thread.sleep(100000); and sample again

Comment: There are no changes :/