# JVM char array occupies lots of memory

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, memory-management, jvm

I have the same problem as asked here [JVM Monitor char array memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908614/jvm-monitor-char-array-memory-usage). But I did not get the clear answer from this question and I couldn't add a comment because of low reputation. So, I am asking from here.

I wrote a multithreaded program that calculates word co-ocurrence frequencies. I am reading words lazily from file and making calculations. In the program, I have a map which holds word pairs and their co-ocurrence counts. After finishing the counting operation, I am writing this map to a file.

## Here is my problem:

After writing frequency map to a file. The size of a file is for example 3gb. But when program runs, used memory is 35gb ram + 5gb swap area. Then I monitor the jvm and the memory picture is like this: [image: memory picture]and garbage collector picture is like this: [image: garbage collector picture]and the parameters overwiew: [image: overview]
How char[] array can occupy this much memory when the output file size is 3gb? Thanks.

## Okey, here is the code that causes this problem:

This code is not multithreaded and used for merging two files which contains co-occurred words and their counts. And this code also causes the same memory usage problem and furthermore this code causes lots of gc calls because of high heap space usage,so normal program cannot run because of stop the world garbage collector:

```
import java.io.{BufferedWriter, File, FileWriter, FilenameFilter}
import java.util.regex.Pattern

import core.WordTuple

import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => mMap}
import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Source}

class PairWordsMerger(path: String, regex: String) {

  private val wordsAndCounts: mMap[WordTuple, Int] = mMap[WordTuple, Int]()
  private val pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
  private val dir: File = new File(path)
  private var sWordAndCount: Array[String] = Array.fill(3)("")
  private var tempTuple: WordTuple = WordTuple("","")
  private val matchedFiles: Array[File] = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter {
    override def accept(dir: File, name: String): Boolean = pattern.matcher(name).matches()
  })

  def merge(): Unit = {
    for(fileName <- matchedFiles) {
      val file: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile(fileName)
      val iter: Iterator[String] = file.getLines()

      while(iter.hasNext) {
//here I used split like this because entries in the file
//are hold in this format: word1,word2,frequency
        sWordAndCount = iter.next().split(",")
        tempTuple = WordTuple(sWordAndCount(0), sWordAndCount(1))
        try {
          wordsAndCounts += (tempTuple -> (wordsAndCounts.getOrElse(tempTuple, 0) + sWordAndCount(2).toInt))
        } catch {
          case e: NumberFormatException => println("Cannot parse to int...")
        }
      }
      file.close()
      println("One pair words map update done")
    }
    writeToFile()
  }

  private def writeToFile(): Unit = {
    val f: File = new File("allPairWords.txt")
    val out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))

    for(elem <- wordsAndCounts) {
      out.write(elem._1 + "," + elem._2 + "\n")
    }
    out.close()
  }
}

object PairWordsMerger {
  def apply(path: String, regex: String): PairWordsMerger = new PairWordsMerger(path, regex)
}
```

Comment: Your application used memory won't necessarily match your output size. As far as memory allocation, java isn't only allocating things in terms of your char array. Without showing any of your code, it's hard to identify what is causing your char array to occupy so much memory. Remember that java cleans up memory with a garbage collector, and isn't as memory efficient as other languages like `C` or `C++`, where you have to explicitly define when to clean up memory.

Comment: I don't think those are "bare" char arrays.  String uses a char array internally, and most of those char[] are going to be Strings.  I don't know of a memory tool that shows you which objects are used by your program directly and aren't part of some other object (but I'd like to find one!).

Comment: Actually looking at that first graph, you also have a huge amount of Tuple and a huge HashEntry.  My guess is that you have a huge HashMap that is holding onto many, many strings that you never delete.

Comment: Hey, thanks  for answers. Other than the frequency map, all other String objects are temporarily used, so i think that they must be garbage collected@BennettYeo The easy to use tool would be very beneficial.. Yes map is holding Strings and counts but when I wrote this map to a file, it only takes 3g @markspace

Comment: If the garbage collector has not run yet, it won't collect unused objects.  Java typically doesn't run the GC until it has to (memory is close to running out), but there's parameters to change this.

Comment: You need to provide relevant code, including the code that writes the output file so we can see its format.

Comment: @WarrenDew I just added the code.

Comment: I’m not good at reading Scala code, but all I see are *string* variables despite you are dealing with counts. So either, you are converting between numbers and `String`s back and forth, or you are using string concatenation excessively. In either case, your code will produce a lot of strings consuming a lot of memory, far more than the files involved. Their temporary nature doesn’t matter when you look at the profiler showing the *total number of allocated objects* rather than the currently allocated objects. But, of course, when you run the JVM with `-Xms35g`, it has no reason to ever do a GC